# How did Maester Mellos know to bring "Moon Tea" to Princess Rhaenyra?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-the-dragon

In episode 1.04 of the *Game of Throne's* spin-off series, *House of the Dragon*, Princess Rhaenyra gets herself into a tryst when her Uncle Daemon sneaks her out of the Red Keep where he eventually takes her to pleasure house. The two begin to engage in sexual acts with each other, until Daemon suddenly stops and abandons Raenyra for a random someone else. This causes Rhaenyra (now undisguised) to run home and give her virginity instead to Christian Cole, a member of the King's Guard Raenyra has shared an important moment with...

However, Otto Hightower, The Hand of the King, has "spies" everywhere insisting that one of them has seen Rhaenyra with Daemon at the pleasure house, as he decides to tell her father, King Viserys about it. Viserys then later questions Rhaenyra, who denies it to anyone who asks her, but by the end of the episode one of the Grand Maesters shows up, Grand Maester Mellos, with Moon Tea (poison) to ensure she does not have a child.

At this point only a handful of people know about Rhaenyra's exploits with Daemon and no one, but Rhaenyra & Cristian know what they did.

So how did this Grand Maester know? Who told him? Viserys? Otto/his spies? Herwyn Strong? Mysaria? Or are they somehow spying themselves??

Answer (score 8):

**King Viserys told Grand Maester Mellos.**

Relevant dialogue (emphasis mine):

> **Rhaenyra:** I'm sorry, what is that?
> **Mellos:** A tea, Princess.
> **From the King.**
> It will rid you of any unwanted consequences.

In the book, *Fire & Blood* (the source material), Mellos (or anyone) bringing Rhaenyra a contraceptive drug after the Daemon and Criston incidents wasn't mentioned at all. Unlike in the TV show, in the book, it is not entirely clear what happened in the Daemon and Criston incidents due to multiple accounts contradicting each other, a la [*Rashomon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon_effect).

Comment: Just because a character says something in dialogue, doesn't make it true. (especially in a series or from source material that plays with "unreliable narrators") There is ZERO confirmation in any other scene that Visery's actually sent them.

Comment: @DarthLocke There is ZERO confirmation that anyone other than King Viserys told Mellos to bring Rhaenyra the tea. The TV show doesn't do the "unreliable narrator" storytelling approach. (The books do, but not the TV show.) I see no reason for Mellos to lie, and it would be out of character for Mellos to lie. Also, lying to the princess that the king sent him could cost him his life.

Comment: Yes, that is why it's SO suspicious, because they chose not to have any confirmation scene to go with it. We know certain "beats" of this story via SOIAF & Fire & Blood, but we don't know copious details and/or which in-universe details are true, which is why I was asking in case the EPs/Writers/Martin might have clarified or perhaps Fire & Blood does (I do not own that book) -- but given the nature of the source material in terms of unreliable narrators and political espionage (ie: magical practitioners who can steel identities or Maesters write the history), I don't think my Q is unfounded.

Comment: @DarthLocke I understand that reasoning for you asking the question. In *Fire & Blood*, Mellos (or anyone) bringing Rhaenyra an abortifacient after the Daemon/Criston incident wasn't mentioned at all. Unlike in the TV show, in the book, it is not entirely clear what happened in the Daemon/Criston incident(s) (and multiple other events) due to multiple accounts contradicting each other.